# SQL LDAP Query problems

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, ldap, linked-server

Recently got tasked to look at this issue but cant fathom out why it's not working. This was created by someone else before my time and im not an uber experienced dba.
Anyway the issue is that some users details are not getting updated in our contact directory and others dont exist at all. I have done some digging and found a SP that uses an ldap query to hit AD and pull the users back. These users all exist in AD and cant see any other issue why they aren't coming through. Part of the proc syntax is an openquery that uses ADSI as a linked server and i am aware of the 1000 row limitation of this. I will post the proc code below and if anyone can see anything obvious, please enlighten me.

```
USE [Web_Repository]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[get_activedirectory]    Script Date: 08/03/2020 11:04:57 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER procedure [dbo].[get_activedirectory]
as
--GET ACTIVE DIRECTORY USERS OF ENABLED ACOUNTS
declare @i integer, @accname varchar(1000), @sql varchar(8000)

if exists (select * from sysobjects where name = 'activedirectory_temp' ) Drop Table activedirectory_temp

CREATE TABLE [activedirectory_temp] (
    [sn] [varchar] (256)   NULL ,
    [GivenName] [varchar] (256)   NULL ,
    [displayName] varchar (256) NULL,
    [Department] [varchar] (256)   NULL ,
    [Title] [varchar] (256)   NULL ,
    [SAMAccountName] [varchar] (256)   NULL ,
    [Company] [varchar] (256)   NULL ,
    [mail] [varchar] (256)   NULL ,
    [physicalDeliveryOfficeName] [varchar] (256)   NULL ,
    [enabled] bit NULL, 
    [wWWHomePage] [varchar] (256) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

set @sql = 'insert into dbname.dbo.activedirectory_temp select top 901 sn, GivenName, displayName, Department, Title, SAMAccountName, Company, mail, physicalDeliveryOfficeName,0 enabled, wWWHomePage from openquery (ADSI,''SELECT sn, GivenName, displayName, Department, Title, SAMAccountName, Company, mail, physicalDeliveryOfficeName, wWWHomePage FROM ''''LDAP://DC=Group,DC=Net'''' WHERE objectCategory = ''''Person'''' AND objectClass = ''''user'''' AND (UserAccountControl = ''''512'''' OR UserAccountControl = ''''640'''' or company = ''''zeroc'''' or SAMAccountName = ''''137499'''' or SAMAccountName = ''''157067'''' or SAMAccountName = ''''WebIE10test'''') ORDER BY SAMAccountName'')'
set @sql = replace(@sql,'dbname',db_name())
exec(@sql)

set @i = @@rowcount

while @i <> 0
begin
    set @accname = (select max(SAMAccountName) from activedirectory_temp)
    --OU=Group Less Restricted
    set @sql = 'insert into dbname.dbo.activedirectory_temp select top 901 sn, GivenName, displayName, Department, Title, SAMAccountName, Company, mail, physicalDeliveryOfficeName,0 enabled, wWWHomePage from openquery (ADSI,''SELECT sn, GivenName, displayName, Department, Title, SAMAccountName, Company, mail, physicalDeliveryOfficeName, wWWHomePage FROM ''''LDAP://DC=Group,DC=Net'''' WHERE objectCategory = ''''Person'''' AND objectClass = ''''user'''' AND (UserAccountControl = ''''512'''' OR UserAccountControl = ''''640'''' or company = ''''zeroc'''' or SAMAccountName = ''''137499'''' or SAMAccountName = ''''157067'''' or SAMAccountName = ''''WebIE10test'''') AND SAMAccountName > ''''####'''' ORDER BY SAMAccountName'')'
    set @sql = replace(@sql,'dbname',db_name())
    set @sql = replace(@sql,'####',@accname)
    exec(@sql)

    set @i = @@rowcount
end

--REMOVE ALL ADMIN & DUMMY ACCOUNTS
update activedirectory_temp
set enabled = 1
where sn > ''
and isnull(givenname,'') > ''
and isnull(title,'') not in ('Resource','Additional')
and isnull(sn,'') <> 'Template'
--and mail is not null
--and left(mail,1) <> '_'

delete from activedirectory_temp
where enabled <> 1

--LOAD DATA INTO LIVE TABLE IF SUCCESSFULL
set @i = (select count(*) from activedirectory_temp)


/*  MN 23/08/2016
    Insert changed to a select distinct to remove duplicate problem for sort order difference between LDAP and SQL
    ie SQL orders local variable @accname (SAMAccountName) natpaint -> N-E-H, whilst LDAP orders N-E-H -> natpaint 
    This causes a duplicate when selecting 901 rows into the temp table  */

if @i > 0
begin
    truncate table activedirectory

    insert into activedirectory (sn,GivenName,displayName,Department,Title,SAMAccountName,Company,mail,physicalDeliveryOfficeName, wWWHomePage)
    select distinct sn,GivenName,displayName,Department,Title,SAMAccountName,Company,mail,physicalDeliveryOfficeName, wWWHomePage
    from activedirectory_temp
end

if exists (select * from sysobjects where name = 'activedirectory_temp' ) Drop Table activedirectory_temp
```

Answer (score 0):

Upon further investigation we discovered it was a seperate process/job that was causing the issue.